# Class which always returns the same instance

Tags: c#, oop

How can I write a class in C# that only returns the "same" instance of an object? Is this effectively a singleton or different? This was mentioned in the book Effective Java 2nd addition.

I use C# 4.0 (no technology barrier).

Comment: Yes, this is the Singleton pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Well best way, as long as it can stay static is just to have a static class, if not use a singleton pattern, there is many posts here about it already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136008/is-this-singleton-implementation-correct-and-thread-safe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a Singleton pattern. You'll find an excellent discussion based on our own Jon Skeet's C# implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550925/singleton-by-jon-skeet-clarification).

Comment: Thanks guys. Just making sure.

Answer (score 1):

If your Singleton object is expensive to create, but isn't used every time your application runs, consider using Lazy.

```
public sealed class LazySingleton
{
    private readonly static Lazy<LazySingleton> instance = 
        new Lazy<LazySingleton>(() => new LazySingleton() );

    private LazySingleton() { }

    public static LazySingleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance.Value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace DesignPatterns
{
    public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private static volatile Singleton instance = null;

        private Singleton() { }

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                   Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref instance, new Singleton(), null);

                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scroll down to "Third Version" in http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html.